# Using Doctrine ODM with FlightPHP

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm, flightphp

I'm trying to use Doctrine's MongoDB ODM with FlightPHP in what I thought would be a pretty quick little project.

I've registered the DocumentManager class with Flight like so:

```
$dm = DocumentManager::create( $connection, $config );

Flight::register('dm', 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager', array($connection,     $config));

// Endpoints
Flight::route( '/api/create', function ( )
{
    $thing = new Thing();

    $dm = Flight::dm();
    $dm->persist( $thing );
    $dm->flush();
} );
```

And it appears that flight tries to call Doctrine's constructor which is protected? What are my options to get around this?

```
Fatal error: Call to protected Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager::__construct() from context 'flight\core\Loader' in /../vendor/mikecao/flight/flight/core/Loader.php on line 116
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DocumentManager class is intended to be constructed through its `create()` static factory method, as is shown in the [Getting Started](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) and [Introduction](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) documentation entries.

Taking a look at Flight's [Registering Classes](https://github.com/mikecao/flight#registering-classes), it only appears to support constructing classes by invoking their constructor. This is in contrast to frameworks such as Silex, which allow you full control over constructing your shared services (see [here](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/services.html#service-definitions)). As-is, I don't see a work-around within Flight's current code, so I would suggest opening an issue or submitting a pull request to [the project](https://github.com/mikecao/flight/issues) to request/add more flexible service construction.

Answer (score 4):

This is resolved in the latest version of Flight

> It should now be possible in the latest commit b9b2d0f. You can register a callable instead of just a classname:

```
Flight::register('db', array('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager','create'), array($connection, $config));
```

Added ability to register callbacks for class instantiation.
https://github.com/mikecao/flight/commit/b9b2d0fa2d75e6b2f606fbd0d9a8059a0f741578
https://github.com/mikecao/flight/issues/105